# Dynamically changing the where clause according to input parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

We are currently having a view in the Oracle DB.Currently I created the web API to accept one input parameter and using them in the particular field in the where clause. Below is the code for the service

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Getdetails(string JRS_NO)
 {

    List<OracleParameter> prms = new List<OracleParameter>();
    List<string> selectionStrings = new List<string>();
    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TGSDataConnection"].ConnectionString;
    using (OracleConnection dbconn = new OracleConnection(connStr))
    {
        DataSet userDataset = new DataSet();
        var strQuery = "SELECT * from LIMS_SAMPLE_RESULTS_VW where JRS_NO =" + JRS_NO;

        var returnObject = new { data = new OracleDataTableJsonResponses(connStr, strQuery, prms.ToArray()) };
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, returnObject, MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"));
        ContentDispositionHeaderValue contentDisposition = null;
        if (ContentDispositionHeaderValue.TryParse("inline; filename=ProvantisStudyData.json", out contentDisposition))
        {
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = contentDisposition;
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

The view has 16 columns in it.Like `REQUEST_ID,JRS_NO,ROOM,SUBMITDATE,DOB`etc I am checking if there is away we can get any of the fields as input parameters and we can change our where clause accordingly.
Like if we calling the API with `api/TGSSampData?JRS_NO=379&SUBMITDATE='01-JAN-2016'` or `api/TGSSampData?ROOM=111&DOB='22-AUG-2014'`. I am not sure if we can dynamically be changing the where clause according to the input parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is a `string`, so of course you **can** modify it however you want, by parametrizing your text. You need to add a seconde parameter in your action method.

An entirely different question is, whether you **should** change the where clause. That can not be immediately answerde with a *yes*. You have to consider that you are receiving your criteria from the HTTP request string, which can contain anything. Your example does already this, which is extremely dangerous:

```
var strQuery = "SELECT * from LIMS_SAMPLE_RESULTS_VW where JRS_NO =" + JRS_NO;
```

You are opening the floodgates for an SQL injection. You are not validating your `JRS_NO` and appending it directly to your query string. This is a huge security risk. If you now also compose the string using a dynamic column name, you multiply the possibilities for an attacker.

So the answer is: You can make your code more dynamic, but you should not compose the query string like you do. Use parameters in your query, which protects you from SQL injection there:

```
"SELECT * from LIMS_SAMPLE_RESULTS_VW where JRS_NO = @Value"
```

You already have `prms` to add your `OracleParameter` to.

As far as making your fields dynamic, create a list of valid columns on server side and validate your input against it. Only if you are sure that the value is legitimate, use it to compose the query.